# CKeditor: missing "Upload" tab on image properties

Tags: image, upload, tabs, ckeditor

I am trying to use the **CKEditor 3.6.2** in a custom CMS. So far I have followed the instructions and downloaded the [ZIP packaged](http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%203.6.2/ckeditor_3.6.2.zip), extracted it and uploaded it in my root path. The problem is that everything works except for the "Upload" tab on the image properties. I tried changing the Upload: hidden true to false in the *image.js* file but still, nothing changed. This happens even on the CKEditor instances of the samples included. So I guess it's something I am missing.

Anyone knows?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for this myself.

You can buy the 'CkFinder' to do this, once you plug it in, the "Upload" Tab will appear.

But, there is a free version that integrates with CKeditor perfectly providing the same features here:

http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/

This is what you are looking for to upload files to your server (and select files from your server!!) using ckeditor.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you customized ckeditor with config.js.
If so, add 'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl', and  'filebrowserImageUploadUrl' in config file too.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  // Other configs
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/ckeditor/pictures';
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ckeditor/pictures';

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem as you. I sloved the problem by generating input like this:

`<%= f.input :body, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: { filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckeditor/pictures', filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckeditor/pictures' } } %>`

Then you'll get what you want.

Comment: I solved it 1.5 year ago but I will keep that solution in mind as well! Thank you! :)